# "At one's death" vs "on one's death"

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

The following genuine examples are taken from Google Books:

> She had left him nothing **on her death** except for her earlier gift
>   of Twickenham Hall and its eighty acres of parkland, against which he
>   had heavy debts.
>
> He had no children, and his nephew was proclaimed throughout his
>   dominions, and ruled them for six years. **On his death** there was a
>   general scramble for power between the governors of the different
>   provinces.
>
> If the husband left his entire estate to his wife, there would be no
>   estate tax **at his death** since his estate passed to a surviving
>   spouse.
>
> As he develops this theme we begin to learn what he takes a "true
>   philosopher" to be, and what he thinks is actually going to happen to
>   him **at his death**.

I was wondering if the two phrases were interchangeable in these examples. Is there any discernible difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, I think that the use of *on* is a "shortened" version of:

> *on* ***the occasion of*** *his death*

while the use of *at* is a "shortened" version of:

> *at **the time of** his death*

Because those two events are inexorably intertwined, there is only a subtle difference in meaning between the two.

I don't think the two are quite interchangeable, but not so much because of a difference in meaning. It's more a matter of context and convention.

Comment: In the provided examples, how does the context prefer one over the other?

Comment: #1 is not so much concerned with _time_ as _occasion_ or _event_. #3 is talking about time (not so much time of day, but at the time of some event). It's very subtle and hard to explain; maybe someone else can do a better job than me.